# UIView cannot be remove after using presentModalViewController

Tags: xcode, uiview

I used a presentModalViewController to present a view and then after I try remove a UView using removeFromSuperview, but its not working anymore.

Before I used the command presentModalViewController , there's no problem in removing a Uiview from superview.

What changed?

Comment: what is wrong? Is the view still on superview or is there an exception? You wrote too little information, -presentModalViewController should not change the behaviour of -removeFromSuperview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `presentModalViewController` is deprecated so you should not be using it.
Per the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you should be using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.

Secondly, if you use any of the `present??ViewController` methods, in order to dismiss it, you should use the appropriate `dismiss??ViewController` like this:

```
// Present the view controller
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

// Later, to dismiss it:
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```